# no more... than / never any more... than

Tags: syntactic-analysis, ambiguity

What are the meanings of these two sentences?

1. Sex is no more boring than work is.
2. There was never any more maturity than there is now.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/no-more-not-any-more) notes:

> We use no more … than or not any more … than to talk about comparative
>   quantities and degrees. No more than is more formal than not any more
>   than:
>
> It does not tell you much. There is no more detail than in the
>   instructions. (formal)
>
> Flying there isn’t any more expensive than getting the train.
>   (informal)

[Longman Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/no-more-than) says:

> no more ... than
>
> used to emphasize that someone or something does not have a particular
>   quality or would not do something
>
> He’s no more fit to be a priest than I am!

I think, according to Longman, the sentence No.1 means sex and work both are not boring at all. But the sentence No.1 indicates that the quantity of maturity in the past was the same as in present time. But I am not sure.

Are these two structures the same? Or they have different usages? Can anyone help me to understand these two sentences?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. It's a simple comparison. The implication is that the quantities being compared are probably about the same, but it's not as strong as saying they are exactly the same, or one is definitely less or more than the other.
"Sex is no more boring than work is" just means sex is either as boring as, or less boring than work.
"There was never any more maturity than there is now" just means there was either the same amount, or less maturity than there is now.